# Изменить размер iframe quill.js

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

При вставке видео с youtube quill вставляет очень маленький iframe. Можно ли как-то изменить его размеры? В идеале видео должно занимать 100% ширины редактора, как это делают картинки. Ничего толкового не нашёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в файлах quill решил проблему так:
В css файле quill js добавил:

```
.ql-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Это помогло увеличить видео, которые вставляются на сайт, решение на самое лучшее, т.к. при обновлении библиотеки нужно будет снова вносить изменения, но другого я не нашёл